# A cloud condenses, compost decomposes, a battery charges, what does a spark do?

Tags: single-word-requests

What's the word that refers to what a spark does as it is forming? "Energizing"? "Igniting"? What I'm looking for is akin to a fire "starting" or "igniting", but the word for what occurs as a spark comes to be.

Edit: One term someone suggested in EE.SE chat is "jumps", but jumps and discharges are more what sparks do once they are fully formed. That's their action. I'm looking for the word for their developing or formation.

Comment: It sparks.  Prior to sparking a charge builds.

Comment: So "a spark charges" is what I'm looking for. Or a spark "builds", "develops", or "forms" probably works too?

Comment: Technically, a spark doesn't exist until the breakdown voltage threshold is reached, and then it happens essentially instantaneously.  But I suppose "a spark builds" is a reasonable metaphor.

Comment: *disintegrate*? *descintillate*?

Comment: A spark 'ignites'. It is a matter of oxidation (flame) or air excitation (electrical). ' It is impossible for a visible spark to form in a vacuum.' [Google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=spark+in+a+vacuum&oq=spark+in+a+vacuum&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.5836j1j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: It doesn't have the sense of building, but "discharging" is what comes to mind for me.

Comment: 'Compost decomposes' does not refer to a formation (of compost)  process. 'Plant matter decomposes to form compost' is perhaps what you mean.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I get what you mean as compost is a product, but I also think of compost as the intermediary stage which is still forming and becoming more complete through decomposition

Comment: I suppose we have to consider _compost_ as ill-defined, gardener-specific. But it takes time to form and be considered as usable compost. Batteries take time to charge. Clouds can form almost instantaneously (though they often then grow...). //  Sparks form / appear. 'Develop' is not really punctive enough.

Comment: At the microscopic level there will the an "aura" of sorts before the actual spark.  With meteorological lightning this aura can build for several seconds before the actual lightning bolt, but with a more mundane spark it would normally only last a fraction of a second and only be perceptible to someone looking closely.

Comment: @Lawrence Done as suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A spark [discharges](https://www.greenfacts.org/glossary/pqrs/spark-discharge.htm).

> Spark discharge
> Similar term(s): microshock.
>
> Definition:
> A momentary electric discharge between two differently charged objects. Sparks cross the air-gap between the objects along a narrow channel, which is visible as a light flash.

Comment: Looks like you beat me to it!

Comment: @user888379 Synchronicity strikes again! You can still give your own version though, and there's a good chance it would be an improvement.

Comment: beat me too! dang

Comment: @Ibf I'm usually a whole lot slower, but that one was a bit too easy for me. I don't mind the competition, though, so go for it if you like. Varied viewpoints add more interest.

Comment: Another term someone suggested in EE.SE chat is "jumps", but jumps and discharges are more what sparks do once they are fully formed. That's their action. I'm looking for the word for their developing or formation.

Comment: They simply charge, and then discharge. The electrostatic charge builds prior to sparking, but really sparks don't exist until they discharge. "A spark is triggered when the electric field strength exceeds approximately 4–30 kV/cm[2] — the dielectric field strength of air. This may cause a very rapid increase in the number of free electrons and ions in the air, temporarily causing the air to abruptly become an electrical conductor in a process called dielectric breakdown." (Wikipedia)

Comment: But "discharge" simply means "spark".  They are one and same -- one does not precede the other.

Comment: @Hot Licks ~ I do hope someone comes up with a better answer, as this is the best I've got.

Comment: Given I'm looking for the word on the other side of a spark's existance - its formation, not necessarily its action, though maybe there's not much difference - I'd say the word I'm looking for is actually "charges". A cloud condenses and accumulates, a battery charges and so does a spark.

Answer (score 3):

A spark '**ignites**'. It is a matter of oxidation (flame) or air excitation (electrical).

> **Ignite the Spark**, Fuel the Fire: Innovative differentiation

[Education Arts](https://education.arts.unsw.edu.au/events/ignite-the-spark-fuel-the-fire-innovative-differentiation-/)

An oxidation (flame) spark is preceded by a rise in temperature/rise in vapour pressure and an electrical spark (air excitation) is preceded by a rise in potential difference.

---

Technical Note :

> It is impossible for a visible spark to form in a vacuum.

[Google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=spark+in+a+vacuum&oq=spark+in+a+vacuum&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.5836j1j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Electrons can jump the gap in a vacuum but they are invisible, there is no spark just a current flow.

Comment: I wouldn't describe "air excitation" specifically as ignition, I would describe it as *ionization* (i.e., the formation of a plasma). Such ionization or discharge can be used to *ignite* another combustable material, e.g., fuel. I suppose spark formation could be an alternative definition of "ignition," but I see only a metaphorical example currently present in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The [Oxford Collocation Dictionary](http://www.freecollocation.com/search?word=spark) lists the following common verbs with spark:

1. ignites
2. kindles
3. flares